# Returning data from a Firebase Closure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

So far I am able to get as far populating my text label once the user logs. So once they do, the homepage says "Welcome johndoe" (johndoe being the username they registered with). However, I also have a Hamburger styled table view that has their profile information containing their username, location and their profile image. I am having trouble populating the username in the tableview with the same username (being johndoe).

I have tried to use a global variable that will hold the username string but i keep getting the default value of "No Name"

```
var username : String = "No Name"

    func getUserName() {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    databaseRef.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let theUserName = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["nameOfUser"] as! String
        self.username = theUserName
        self.nameOfUserLabel.text! = "Welcome \(self.username)"
        //this prints out the correct label by saying "Welcome johndoe"
    }
    print("The name of the user is: \(self.username)")
    //for example it would print out in the console: "No Name"

}
```

By using the username value, I am trying to assign that to my profile items table view:

```
func createProfileArray() -> [ProfileItems] {
    var tempProfileItems: [ProfileItems] = []

    let profileItem = ProfileItems(profileImage: UIImage(named: "defaultUser")!, nameTitle: username, location: "Toronto")

    tempProfileItems.append(profileItem)


    return tempProfileItems
}
```

However, once the tableview is loaded it just says "No name". The goal is to have same user name like they have on the welcome title label.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please lookup "asynchronous". BTW - a function named `getXXX` should have some sort of return value. You should rename that method to `loadUserName` or something similar.

Comment: Sure, will change the name. But what exactly do I do with asynchronous?

Comment: Lookup what it means. I would imagine the Firebase documentation makes mention of it.

Comment: Please read http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ and then http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/

Answer (score 1):

You can't the call to the method that gets the name is asynchonous ( `observeSingleEvent` ) , so look to real sequence it's executed

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return } // 1

databaseRef.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let theUserName = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["nameOfUser"] as! String
    self.username = theUserName
    self.nameOfUserLabel.text! = "Welcome \(self.username)" // 3
    //this prints out the correct label by saying "Welcome johndoe"
}
print("The name of the user is: \(self.username)") // 2
```

You' ll always see **No Name** out of the closure completion